# Android build: Fennec with chromium rendering Engine

Tags: chromium, gecko, blink, fennec

I built the chromium for android following these instructions https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions .
I got the content shell only not the full browser.
Then, I built the Firefox for Android. I successfully got the Full web browser. But the performance of the chrome content shell was much much better than that of Firefox Android build. Now, I want to try building the Firefox Android using chromium rendering Engine, Blink replacing the Gecko rendering Engine. How much is the difficulty level and how can I start.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Chromium uses Blink (earlier Webkit) as its rendering, and V8 for Javascript interpretation along with various 3rd party dependencies. Even though Content shell is a small browser (sans complex UI of Chromium) it is functional and a wrapper over Blink. Having said that fitting Blink with Firefox (instead of Gecko) will be a new project by itself, probably you can try building Webview, so that you can build a simple browser itself in android. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Chromium - Open Source project 
Chrome- Google's proprietary software +  Chromium

In Android only Google Chrome can be installed as APK, wherease Chromium can be built as content shell or used through WebView

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/zMDKC2x9o5w

Comment: Do Yandex.Browser or Opera browser provide their UI as described in the chromium discusion ?

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/zMDKC2x9o5w

Comment: Thanks subbul for your reply. I have got a reply from Mozilla Forums too. here is the link: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=2820443 and got the reply from the chromium forums about the UI,the Yandex.browser and Opera browser are not providing their UI as an open source.